# Cisco 3725 - ping encapsulation failed

Tags: cisco, ping, trunk

I am unable to ping from R1 to R2. `debug ip packet detail` returns `IP: s=172.16.12.1 (local), d=172.16.12.2 (FastEthernet0/0.12), len 100, encapsulation failed`. I understand this means it can't resolve an arp address. I am looking for some guidance on what could be causing this.

I am using GNS3 to test some configurations. I have three 3725 routers. One acting as a switch (R1, R2, SW1). `ip cef` is enabled on all three devices.

`R1` and `R2` connect to `SW1`, from their `f0/0` to `f1/1` & `F1/2` respectively. `R1` & `R2` have subinterfaces enabled on `f0/0.12` VLAN 12. `SW1 f1/1` & `f1/2` are both assigned to `vlan 12`.

Is there a feature on `SW1` I need to disable/enable? What am I missing?

`R1` config

```
interface FastEthernet0/0.12  
 encapsulation dot1Q 12  
 ip address 172.16.12.1 255.255.255.0
```

`R2` config

```
interface FastEthernet0/0.12  
 encapsulation dot1Q 12  
 ip address 172.16.12.2 255.255.255.0
```

`SW1` config

```
interface FastEthernet1/1  
 switchport access vlan 12  
 switchport mode trunk  
 duplex full  
 speed 100  
!  
interface FastEthernet1/2  
 switchport access vlan 12  
 switchport mode trunk  
 duplex full  
 speed 100
```

Comment: Did you create vlan 12 on Sw1?

Comment: @Ron Agh (facepalm). I copy/pasted a sequence of commands with the vlan assignments. Never really looked at whether they took or not. The 3725 uses the old `vlan database` syntax, so the vlans were never created. I just never checked that. My mistake. If you make an answer out of this I'll mark it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you can forward traffic on a VLAN, you have to create it in the switch's VLAN database.  For older switches, there is a separate configuration mode for VLANs.  From privileged (enable) mode type:

```
switch# vlan database
switch(vlan)# vlan 12
switch(vlan)# exit
switch#
```